# If Function error or Parameters error?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get the MinValue and MaxValue to be considered and print an error message and then continue with the loop.

It's supposed to check the input with the set parameters and if input goes on either side of the parameters then it should print the error message and then continue with the loop! But it seems to be skipping the If functions and printing the "Number is 'x'".

```
   def inputInt(prompt, errorMessage = 'Invalid input - Try again.', minValue = 3 , maxValue = None):
while True:
    value = input('Enter a value:')
    try:             
        return int(value)
    except ValueError:
        print(errorMessage)

    if (minValue != 'None' and value < minValue):
            print(errorMessage = 'Value below Minimum')

    if (maxValue != 'None' and value > maxValue):
            print(errorMessage = 'Value above Maximum')

   value = inputInt('Enter an int: ')
   print('Value is', value)

    def inputFloat(prompt, errorMessage = 'Invalid input - Try again.', minValue ='None', maxValue = 'None'):
while True:
    value = input('Enter a value:')
    try:             
        return float(value)
    except ValueError:
        print(errorMessage)

    if (minValue != 'None' and int(value) < minValue):
        print(errorMessage = 'Value below Minimum')


    if (maxValue != 'None' and int(value) < maxValue):
        print(errorMessage = 'Value above Maximum')

    value = inputFloat('Enter an int: ')
    print('Value is', value)
```

Comment: do you understand what the `return` statement does?

Comment: oh hi kurt... this is code from [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36181405/5827215) so I already know you don't understand `return`...

Comment: I'm not sure why you are using `=` in `print(errorMessage = 'Value...')` I think you want a comma instead but not sure... as well `if (maxValue != 'None' ...):` might want to be checking against `None` instead of `"None"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`return` exits the function and "returns" to where ever it was called:

```
def f():
    return 1
    raise RuntimeError("Function continued after return?!?!")
print( f() ) #will not raise the error, prints 1
```

so to do extra stuff after converting you need to store it as a variable then return it at the end:

```
while True:
    value = input(...) #you still probably want to use the prompt variable here
    try:
        value = float(value)
    except ValueError:
        print(errorMessage)
        continue #continue with loop, go back to top of loop

    #other code here

    return value
```